# Is there a way I could customize the Time Dimension Table in Visual Studio or in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way I could customize the Time Dimension Table in Visual Studio or in SQL Server?

My manager wants me to create a Time Dimension table into this kind of set-up/design.
I am hoping to customize it in Australian setup in Visual Studio.

Imagine that the Date sample below is in excel sheet. I'm doing this manually in excel because I don't know how to customize it the way my Manager wants it in Visual Studio. Otherwise, I'm suppose to do this manually from year 2005 to 2025 in excel and import it to sql server which is actually not a good idea. But this is the only option that I could think of. I badly need help.

```
PK_Date     DateName                      Year          Year_Name
2005-07-01  Friday, July 01, 2005         2005-12-31    2005
2005-07-02  Saturday, July 02, 2005       2005-12-31    2005
2005-07-03  Sunday, July 03, 2005         2005-12-31    2005
2005-07-04  Monday, July 04, 2005         2005-12-31    2005
2005-07-05  Tuesday, July 05, 2005        2005-12-31    2005
2005-07-06  Wednesday, July 06, 2005      2005-12-31    2005

Half_Year   Half_Year_Name      Quarter       Quarter_Name
2008-12-31  Second Half 2008    2008-09-30    Q3, 2008
2008-12-31  Second Half 2008    2008-09-30    Q3, 2008
2008-12-31  Second Half 2008    2008-09-30    Q3, 2008
2008-12-31  Second Half 2008    2008-09-30    Q3, 2008
2008-12-31  Second Half 2008    2008-09-30    Q3, 2008
2008-12-31  Second Half 2008    2008-09-30    Q3, 2008


Month       Month_Name   Week       Week_Name
2008-07-31  Jul-08       8/5/2008   WE: 5-8-08
2008-07-31  Jul-08       8/12/2008  WE: 12-8-08
2008-07-31  Jul-08       8/19/2008  
2008-07-31  Jul-08       8/26/2008

Day_Of_Year Day_Of_Year_Name    Day_Of_Half_Year    Day_Of_Half_Year_Name
183         Day 183                  1                 Day 1
184         Day 184                  2                 Day 2
185         Day 185                  3                 Day 3
186         Day 186                  4                 Day 4


Day_Of_Quarter  Day_Of_Quarter_Name   Day_Of_Month  Day_Of_Month_Name
1                    Day 1                  1            Day 1
2                    Day 2                  2            Day 2
3                    Day 3                  3            Day 3
4                    Day 4                  4            Day 4

Day_Of_Week  Day_Of_Week_Name   Week_Of_Year    Week_Of_Year_Name
3            Day 3               27                 Wk 27
4            Day 4               27                 Wk 27
5            Day 5               27                 Wk 27
6            Day 6               27                 Wk 27


Month_Of_Year  Month_Of_Year_Name   Month_Of_Half_Year  Month_Of_Half_Year_Name
7              Month 7                   1                Month 1
7              Month 7                   1                Month 1
7              Month 7                   1                Month 1
7              Month 7                   1                Month 1

Month_Of_Quarter  Month_Of_Quarter_Name  Quarter_Of_Year  Quarter_Of_Year_Name
1                 Month 1                 3                Q3
1                 Month 1                 3                Q3
1                 Month 1                 3                Q3

Half_Year_Of_Year   Half_Year_Of_Year_Name  Financial_Year
2                   Jul to Dec 2008          2009-06-30
2                   Jul to Dec 2008          2009-06-30
2                   Jul to Dec 2008          2009-06-30
2                   Jul to Dec 2008          2009-06-30


Financial_Year      Financial_Year_Name  Financial_Half_Year
2009-06-30          2008-2009            2008-12-31
2009-06-30          2008-2009            2008-12-31
2009-06-30          2008-2009            2008-12-31
2009-06-30          2008-2009            2008-12-31
2009-06-30          2008-2009            2008-12-31
2009-06-30          2008-2009            2008-12-31

Financial_Half_Year_Name
Jul-Dec 2008-2009
Jul-Dec 2008-2009
Jul-Dec 2008-2009
Jul-Dec 2008-2009
Jul-Dec 2008-2009
Jul-Dec 2008-2009
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I'd be happier to comply if these certain controls would help

Comment: Huh? Which "controls"?